# Error while creating site template in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-template

I have created a site template which I will be using in the future to create sub sites.

But when I try to create the site template, I am getting the following error.

> Feature definition with Id a0a1065d-0775-4fbc-9222-b1c5eacb3a80 failed validation, file 'template1ListInstances\ElementsFields.xml', line 220, character 273: The 'SystemInstance' attribute is not allowed

Anyone have idea about this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, you should check **wss.xsd** file:

“C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\XML\wss.xsd”

https://erroreimprevisto.wordpress.com/2016/08/01/error-saving-template-sharepoint-2016-attribute-is-not-allowed